# Why am I getting a random ordered array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, sorting, axios

I'm currently trying to develop a dashboard application in React.js.
I'm trying to fill an array of objects and map them in a list.

For every object I have to make an axios GET call to my server in order to get all the data.
When I try to read the objects from the array I get a different order than I'm supposed to. The preferred output is that the objects in the array are sorted by DateTime.

My guess is that it has to do with threading and that the first completed request will be inserted before the others.

Does anyone know if there is a better way to what I'm doing now? Or if I'm forgetting something.

This is the main component where I perform my logic

```
const [shipments, setShipments] = useState([]);

    async function createRows(shipmentId){
      // The incoming id's are in correct order

      const details = await getShipmentDetails(shipmentId);
      // From this point on the responses are in a different order each time it's ran

      let row = {
        shipmentId: details.shipmentId,
        shipmentReference: details.shipmentReference,
        shipmentDateTime: details.shipmentDateTime,
        shipmentItems: details.shipmentItems,
      }
      
      if(shipments.map(s => s.shipmentId).indexOf(row.shipmentId) == -1){

        setShipments(rows => [...rows, row])
      }
    }

    async function retrieveShipments(){ 
      const amount = 5;
      await connectToBol();

      let allShipments = await getShipments();
      allShipments.splice(amount, (allShipments.length-amount + 1))

      if(allShipments.length > 0){
        allShipments.forEach(async shipment => { 
          await createRows(shipment.shipmentId);
        })
      }
    }


    useEffect(() => {
      retrieveShipments()
    }, []);
```

This is the method that performs the axios request

```
export async function getShipmentDetails(shipmentId){

    const response = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/shipments/${shipmentId}`,{
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + <token>
        }
    })
        
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error: ', error);
    });

    return response.data; 
}
```

Below is the output I'm currently getting
[image]

Comment: I tried that, but the output did not change. This is how I translated the solution to my code. Without success; 
    shipments.sort((a, b) => a.shipmentDateTime - b.shipmentDateTime);

Comment: Yes thank you! It's the same answer as TKoL mentioned below and it works now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to focus on how to solve your problem, I'm going to focus on the question asked in the title if that's okay:

Why am I getting a random ordered array?

Well, here's the situation: you're using a `forEach` and making a bunch of api calls

```
    allShipments.forEach(async shipment => { 
      await createRows(shipment.shipmentId);
    })
```

It may not be obvious, but just because you've used `await` in a `.forEach` loop does NOT mean that each item is processed in order - in fact, what's happening is all of the `createRows` calls are queued synchronously.

If I do `[1,2,3].forEach(v => someAsyncFunc(v));`, it calls `someAsyncFunc(1)` and then `someAsyncFunc(2)` and then `someAsyncFunc(3)`, but 2 and 3 are called without waiting for 1 to finish.

So, if by some miracle `someAsyncFunc(2)` finishes before `someAsyncFunc(1)` does, you may end up with out-of-order results. That's what I believe is happening to you, and why you're asking this question.

If you want `someAsyncFunc(2)` to run AFTER `someAsyncFunc(1)` finishes, you don't do a `forEach` loop, you do a `for...of` loop

```
for (let x of [1,2,3]) {
    await someAsyncFunc(x);
}
```

Then, 2 will start only after 1 finishes.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I did not know that I had to use a for...of loop. It works now and the rows are in the right order

Comment: @DiégoCup for the record, there is still a way to do a `forEach` style loop and order the results afterward, idk if you're interested in that.

Comment: If you can show me, ye I would love to know! Still kind of new to React but I always want to learn more :). It can definitely be helpful for later

Comment: @DiégoCup since each async function call creates a Promise, what you could do if you wanted is make an array of promises inside your `forEach`. This array of promises would be made in the same order as your input data. Once you have your array of promises completely built with all the promises inside it, you can use `Promise.all(arrayOfPromises)`, which gives you an array of results that are in the same order as your promises.